# BinaryFormatter.Serialize with MemoryStream issue

Tags: vb.net, serialization, binaryformatter

I am having an issue using BinaryFormatter.Serialize.

I have this generic extension method to "clone" an object via binary serialization:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function CloneViaSerialization(ByRef Obj as System.Object)
   Dim NewObj As System.Object
   Using MS As New System.IO.MemoryStream
      Dim Formatter as New BinaryFormatter
      Formatter.Serialize(MS, Obj)
      Debug.WriteLine("MS LENGTH = " & MS.Length)
      MS.Position = 0
      NewObj = Formatter.Deserialize(MS)
   End Using
   Return NewObj
End Function
```

I also have a class called "Mode" which has a method "Clone" as follows:

```
Friend Function Clone()
   Dim NewMode as Mode = Me.CloneViaSerialization
   Return NewMode
End Function
```

Within my GUI, I have a function that allows a selected Mode object to be cloned.  The user enters a series of new mode names and the routine cycles through those new names creating clones of the selected mode:

```
Private Sub MakeClones(ByRef ModeToClone as Mode, ByVal CloneNames as List(Of String))
   For Each CloneName as String in CloneNames
      Dim NewMode as Mode = ModeToClone.Clone
      NewMode.Name = CloneName
      ParentObject.Modes.Add(NewMode)
   Next
End Sub
```

So basically one or more clones of the selected Mode object ought to be created, the Name property set to the correct value, and the new Mode objects added to the parent.  This involves X number of calls to the Mode.Clone method and in-turn X calls to the CloneViaSerialization extension method.

Here's my issue.  During multiple calls of CloneViaSerialization, the MemoryString length (as displayed at the Debug.WriteLine statement) is almost double what is was the previous call.  For example, making five clones, the debug output is:

> MS LENGTH = 106882
>   MS LENGTH = 188048
>   MS LENGTH = 350482
>   MS LENGTH = 675350
>   MS LENGTH = 1325086

This is killing performance.  Anything more that about 7 or 8 clones brings the app to a halt.  Why would this happen?  The USING block ought to ensure the MemoryString is disposed of, right?  Shouldn't a new MemoryString be created each time?  I would think since the same original Mode object is the source for the serialization, the MemoryString length would be the same.  Any ideas?  What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the other properties of the Mode class? Is there a property that allows Modes to reference other Modes?

Comment: No.  The other properties are all String, Int16, or List(of Int16).  Even so, I would think that since it's the same Mode object being cloned multiple times, the size of the MemoryString ought to always be the same, right?

Comment: Yea, that is odd. Is there a reason you are cloning using Serialization instead of just using `base.MemberwiseClone()`?

Comment: Well, yes and no.  I was using the Serialization clone for all my classes to keep the Clone methods common (there are other classes I can't just use a shallow copy for).  However, breaking that mindset and using MemberwiseClone for the Mode class seems to do the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: @Steve I posted an answer based on the comments with an implementation for Clone on Mode. MemberwiseClone by itself won't give you a copy of your list in the cloned object. If my post answers your question sufficiently, you can just click the checkmark to the left of it to accept. Hope that helps.

Comment: Well...  unfortunately your idea about implementing ICloneable won't work because I need to pass a parameter to the Clone method (I've somewhat simplified my code in this example).  Now, what I've found is that no matter what object I try to clone via my CloneViaSerialization extension method, the DEBUG out is ALWAYS the values I listed in my original post.  I've got Clone methods similar to the Mode class in classes called RF, PD, Antenna, etc and they ALL show that exponential growth during a clone loop.  Getting weirder...

Comment: In that case, don't implement ICloneable, just create a DeepClone method like what I've shown below that uses MemberwiseClone.

Comment: Also, do all of these classes have a common base class or something? I still don't see anything wrong with the extension method, so you would think there must be something up with the data that's getting passed in.

Comment: They do inherit from a common Parametric class which might be an issue, but I can't see anything obvious.  Regardless, the CloneViaSerialization is also used for cloning classes with just regular old string/int/boolean properties and it's taking way longer than the MemberwiseClone.  I'm just abandoning the clone via serialization concept...

Comment: Yea, judging from what you posted I would look at the base class they inherit from. Maybe there's something funky going on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your `CloneViaSerialization` is consuming large amounts of memory, the code you posted seems ok to me (although one possible explanation could just be that the data being cloned is large).  An alternative approach is to just implement `ICloneable` on your `Mode` class and set up your `Clone` function to do a deep copy of your object.

```
Public Class Mode 
    Implements ICloneable

    Private m_Prop1 As String
    Public Property Prop1() As String
        Get
            Return m_Prop1
        End Get
        Set
            m_Prop1 = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Prop2 As Int16
    Public Property Prop2() As Int16
        Get
            Return m_Prop2
        End Get
        Set
            m_Prop2 = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Prop3 As List(Of Int16)
    Public Property Prop3() As List(Of Int16)
        Get
            Return m_Prop3
        End Get
        Set
            m_Prop3 = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        Dim objClone as Mode
        objClone = MemberwiseClone()
        If Not Me.Prop3 Is Nothing Then
            objClone.Prop3 = new List(Of Int16)
            objClone.Prop3.AddRange(Me.Prop3)
        End If
        Return objClone
    End Function

End Class
```

Please be aware that in the `Clone` function, we need to do a separate copy of the `List(Of Int16)`. `MemberwiseClone` will copy references into the new object it creates, so if we don't create a new `List(Of Int16)` and manually copy the values in then we'll wind up with a reference to the original list in the clone.

I also should point out that some people may have a problem implementing `ICloneable` and having it do a deep copy, since `MemberwiseClone` only does shallow copies. If that bothers you then you can always rename `Clone` to `DeepClone` and remove the `ICloneable` interface.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The deep clone concept is going to work for me.  Unfortunately it requires custom Clone methods for a couple dozen classes (which I was hoping to clone generically using the CloneViaSerialization), but oh well.  Working functionality is more important that easy of code maintenance...  Thanks for your help.